# Can't save work/edits to Craft,

Tags: error-message, error

We're developing a new site using Craft. When I'm at work I can save all the work I have done on the site fine. But when I'm at home (using BT broadband), my ability to save any edits I make to the site is very patchy - sometimes it works O.K., more often than not I get the following error message:

> The site can't be reached; The connection was re-set

I've tried using Chrome and Firefox - but same thing happens.

Any ideas?  I'm not a web-expert so answers in layman's terms much appreciated!

Comment: You running any antivirus/firewall software on your home computer? Maybe that's interfering?